# JavaScript Конвертировать Латинские буквы в Кириллицу

Tags: javascript

Привет всем, у меня такое задание, нужно написать программу которая будет конвертировать латинские буквы в кириллицу, это можно легко сделать если создать два массива пример

```
var en = ["q","w","e","r","t","y"];
var ru = ["й","ц","у","к","е","н"];
```

но у меня в задании написано что, надо чтобы элементы во втором массиве были разбросаны не по порядку.

Comment: И да только на Javascript Native, без  jQuery b т.п

Comment: Чем вызвано упомянутое ограничение в задании?

Comment: ну и пусть не по порядку - позиции-то соответствовать должны все равно. зачем вам порядок?

Comment: Чтобы в цикле индекс соответствовал

Answer (score 0):

Мы можем отсортировать массив после разброса:

```js
var en = ["a","d","c","b","f","e"];
var ru = ["а","в","б","д","г","е"];
console.log(ru);
console.log(en);
en.sort();
ru.sort();
console.log(ru);
console.log(en);
```